# My Xbox games get pixelated and barely load when I play them

Tags: xbox-one

So. This problem has been accruing recently after unplugging my Xbox for a day or 2. When I plug it back in, all of my games are slightly laggy and the graphics on the games are terrible. Half the time, it kicks me from the loading screen and says, "There was a connection problem" or something like that.  I have a feeling it has to do something with the physical Xbox but I don't know what it is. Is there a way I can fix this?

ALSO, my internet connection is totally fine. My ping is always around 20-50. So, I don't think it's my wifi.
(This is a Xbox one btw)

Comment: Did you turn the XBox OFF before unplugging it? If you didn't, you probably *#&$d the system.

Comment: @Eristheguest Come to think of it. I did unplug the Xbox while it was on. Is that what the problem is?

Comment: YEah, most likely.

Comment: @Eristheguest is there any possible way I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

OK. Turns out. I had to reset my Xbox multiple times and reconnect it to the internet. As long as I keep it plugged up, it should be fine.

Comment: Good for you, you found a way!